# Python requests exception handling: How to get more verbose (user-friendly) error message?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

Let's suppose I have some function:

```
def get_result(url):
    try:
        return requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': random.choice(USER_AGENTS)}).text
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        message = 'Connection to {0} failed. \n {1}'
        print message.format(url, e)
        sys.exit(0)
```

**Case #1** "bad url syntax"
url = 'http://google'

```
...
 connection to http://google failed. 
 HTTPConnectionPool(host='google', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd417ece350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname',))
...
```

**Case #2** "non-existing url"
url = 'http://smth_non_existing.com'

```
...
connection to http://smth_non_existing.com failed. 
 HTTPConnectionPool(host='smth_non_existing.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe196d4a3d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
...
```

So I want just to print the 'last part' of the error message. In first case *"No address associated with hostname"* and second one *"Name or service not known"*

Answer (score 0):

I found text message that you need - `e.args[0].args[1].args[1]`. It unclear but it prints:

```
Connection to http://google failed. 
 No address associated with hostname
```

Code:

```
def get_result(url):
    try:
        return requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': random.choice(USER_AGENTS)}).text
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        message = 'Connection to {0} failed. \n {1}'
        print message.format(url, e.args[0].args[1].args[1])
        sys.exit(0)
```